# C# - Writing responseStream to context.response.outputstream

Tags: c#, asp.net

Our ASP.net app needs to relay some requests to another server, get the data and serve it. We can download the data to a file and serve it or directly serve the response stream from origin server to client. Data includes js/css/images/font files/mp3 etc.

```
HttpWebRequest forwardRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(remoteUrl);

                forwardRequest.ContentType = context.Request.ContentType;
                forwardRequest.UserAgent = context.Request.UserAgent;
                forwardRequest.Method = context.Request.HttpMethod;

                //add post check

                HttpWebResponse newResponse = (HttpWebResponse)forwardRequest.GetResponse();

                MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                newResponse.GetResponseStream().CopyTo(ms);

                context.Response.ContentType = newResponse.ContentType;
                context.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(ms.GetBuffer());
                ms.Close();

                context.Response.Flush();
                context.Response.Close();
                context.Response.End();
```

How can I directly pass `newResponse.GetResponseStream()` to `context.Response.OutputStream`.

Comment: Note: `.GetBuffer()` returns the **oversized** backing array; I suspect that the `MemoryStream` is not needed here (and is actively harmful), but if you *need* to use it, you should only look at the first `.Length` bytes from `.GetBuffer()` - for example `dest.Write(ms.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)ms.Length);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't pass the stream directly, but you can conveniently write one to the other (which will create a read/write-loop internally):

```
sourceStream.CopyTo(destinationStream);
```

Comment: I hope that would do exactly the same thing which passing stream would have done, i.e. improving peformance without downloading the whole file first

Comment: @adnankamili well in theory it does, but it depends on whether the **response** is buffering internally; but yes, a read-write loop (which is what `CopyTo` does) can support proxying the response without downloading it all first. The `MemoryStream` implementation, by contrast, explicitly downloads first.